# How to embed multiple calendars?

Tags: google-calendar

I've been trying for an hour now. And it's bugging me.

1. I have a central google calendar account (let's call this account "A"). Then I have my own account and so do other members of my team.
2. I created my calendar and set sharing for the account "A" and so did other members of my team.
3. Now I'm trying to embed all of the calendars into a web page using account "A".

When I use google embeding helper I can only show "A's" own calendar. Whenever I check checkbox to add another calendar the place where it shows preview just says "The website is not available." No matter the browser.

I've already tried granting full privileges to no avail.

Has anybody been successful with this?

---

Edit: I found out that this is caused by non-gmail accounts. Google has problems with non-gmail acconts almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is caused by non-gmail accounts. Google has problems with non-gmail acconts almost everywhere.